# Нужен уникальный ключ на exe файл python

Tags: python, безопасность, хеширование, hashlib

Нужно защитить программу таким образом, чтобы ее нельзя было просто скопировать и отослать дальше, то есть пользователь запускается программу у него спрашивают ключ, если он правильный, то программа выполняется, если нет, то ничего не происходит, пробовал:

```
import hashlib
import platform

identifier = platform.platform() 
key = hashlib.sha256(identifier.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Hо если делать .exe на своем компьютере и отсылать его пользователям - ключ получается одинаковым.

Comment: Ну а что должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохой идентификатор для ключа.Там название операционной системы.

```
>>> platform.platform() 
'Linux-5.6.3-arch1-1-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5'
```

Используй getnode или получай чтото поуникальнее: мак адрес, id пользователя(для виндовс), серийник жесткого диска...

```
from uuid import getnode
client_id = getnode()
```

там число уникальное для компьютера на основе мак адреса

```
>>> getnode()
247207014807830
```

Comment: большое спасибо! я правильно понял, что ключ будет одинаковом только на одинаковых ноутбуках или пк?

Comment: getnode будет везде разный, кроме случаев когда его подделают.

Comment: спасибо еще раз)